# What does casting a pointer difference to "int*" mean?

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

```
ptr3 = (int *) (ptr2 – ptr1)
```

`ptr2 - ptr1` gives the difference between the subscripts. Casting `ptr2 - ptr1` to an integer confuses me since it is already an integer. Why do that?
EDIT:- ptr1, ptr2,ptr3 are all pointers

Comment: What's the type of `ptr1` and `ptr2`? Please always provide complete, compileable code in your questions. Also, where did you find this code, and what's the surrounding code? We need to know this in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: For some peculiar reason, the result of subtracting two pointers is cast to an _`int *`_ (`int` pointer) — which is basically meaningless.  If the `int *` is used unmodified, it is likely to crash the program.  There is no good explanation for why it is done like that; it shouldn't be done like that.  Discuss with the person who wrote the code.  If they're unavailable, fix it cautiously.

Comment: But you aren't casting to an integer but to a pointer? Which should indeed confuse you, I have no idea why anyone would do that.

Comment: Edit :- ptr1, ptr2 ,ptr3 are all pointers. I found this piece of code online while trying to learn pointers from the web. Also thank you for taking time to read my question!!

Comment: *I found this piece of code online while trying to learn pointers from the web.* Unless the example you found was showing incorrect use of pointers, never use the site you got that from again.  The difference between two pointers is the number of objects between the two addresses - if and only if those two pointers refer to the same array of objects.  Any other usage is incorrect, and in any case the result will **never** be another pointer.  Again - if the site you found that on doesn't clearly state the code is **wrong**, that site is **complete garbage**.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer subtraction yields the result of type `ptrdiff_t`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6/P9

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header [...]

Here, the attempt is to cast that to an `int *`, which does not appear to be proper.